# how to tell what intent data is supported for a system activity

Tags: android

I am inspecting this piece of code (it opens Usage Settings permissions for a particular app):

```
val intent = Intent("android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS")
val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.my.example", null)
intent.data = uri
context.startActivity(intent)
```

I understand the `"USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS"` part, it is documented: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS

But how did the author of this code come up with the `"package"` intent data? Is there any list of allowed intent data for each of intents?

I cannot find any info about this in the docs. Maybe there's something in the Android source code I can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it opens Usage Settings permissions for a particular app

Not necessarily. There is no requirement that it works on any particular device.

> Maybe there's something in the Android source code I can read?

The source code to the AOSP edition of the Settings app has two activities that respond to that `Intent` action:

```xml
        <activity
            android:name="Settings$UsageAccessSettingsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/usage_access_title">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
                android:value="com.android.settings.applications.manageapplications.ManageApplications" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.PRIMARY_PROFILE_CONTROLLED"
                       android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="Settings$AppUsageAccessSettingsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/usage_access_title">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.android.settings.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
                android:value="com.android.settings.applications.UsageAccessDetails"/>
        </activity>
```

(code from [an Android 12 branch](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r31:packages/apps/Settings/AndroidManifest.xml))

The second one has `<data android:scheme="package"/>`, lining up with that `Uri` from your code snippet.

Just bear in mind that device manufacturers routinely change the Settings app, and there is no requirement for them to support this particular activity.